# Should recommendation questions be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I agree that the Food/alcohol pairing questions should be on topic because there are reference-able guidelines and cultural norms for those beyond opinion.

However I noticed a few questions asking for [a recommendation for a spirit for a specific cocktail](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/5072/what-is-the-best-type-of-gin-to-use-in-a-gin-martini) or for a beer [that matched a certain group of flavors/notes](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/954/spicy-hard-cider)  or questions about [sourcing beers in a specific locality](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3385/growler-fillups-in-san-jose-south-bay-area) that seem to be really low quality/opinion-based/overly specific.

I worry that allowing these sorts of questions will open up a flood stream of opinion based list answers.

Comment: From what I have been seeing there are a few different tags that really need to be outlined correctly so people know exactly how to use them I agree with your worry and I have added it to the list of tags I am going to have a long look at